# Moving AngularJS app to pushState

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pushstate

A lot of the time in our AngularJS applications, we'll have URLs hard coded as in the tutorial presented on the official Angular site, eg:

```
<a href="#/phones/{{phone.id}}">
```

Couple of questions in regards to this.

- If moving from `#/` to pushState, does one manually have to go and rewrite every single URL in their application? In this case, we'd have to rewrite the above to `
- What about reverse compatibility with older browsers? If we go and rewrite all of our URLs, will Angular know to drop a `#` in front of URLs on its own, or is this something the developer needs to handle?

Wish there was more pushState documentation out there, this is a bit confusing for a new comer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes you have to manually change all those links.
2. Yes, angular will automatically add the `#` if there's no support for the HTML5 history API.

**P.S.** You never needed the `#` there to begin with. Angular adds that automatically for you.

Comment: So there's no reason to ever change links then, even if you are not building with pushState in mind, just keep the explicit `#` out of links and you won't have to change them when you do move to pushState is what I'm getting out of this. Which is super useful to know.

Comment: @randombits - Correct. No need to ever have the `#` in there.